# count for 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to make a COUNT for 2 different tables, I try the next code, but it gives me the result just for gal table . what I need to modify to get a number of rows how is duplicate in gal and in TLP

the code is :

```
SELECT name, GIVEN_NAME, mail, COUNT(*) AS DUPS 
FROM   Glob 
WHERE  ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT email1 
                     FROM   TLP
                     WHERE  GLOB.mail = TLP.email1 ) 
         AND GLOB.mail IS NOT NULL ) 
        AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT LASTNAME 
                         FROM   TLP
                         WHERE  GLOB.NAME = TLP.LASTNAME ) 
             AND GLOB.NAME IS NOT NULL )
        AND
              (NOT EXISTS (SELECT FIRSTNAME 
                     FROM   TLP 
                     WHERE  GLOB.GIVEN_NAME = TLP.FIRSTNAME ) 
         AND GLOB.NAME IS NOT NULL ) 
         AND GLOB.COUNTRY='Germany'
         GROUP BY NAME, GIVEN_NAME, MAIL
         HAVING (COUNT(*)>1);
```

Comment: It's quite hard to understand the query as its currently phrased. Could you please share your tables' structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i don't know how to do this, but I would try

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you are trying to do here, based on your query. If you are just looking for a quick and dirty row count, you can wrap it in a common table expression like this.

```
;with cte_mycount AS(
SELECT NAME, 
       given_name, 
       mail 
FROM   gal 
WHERE  ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT email1 
                     FROM   tcpd_personel 
                     WHERE  gal.mail = tcpd_personel.email1) 
         AND gal.mail IS NOT NULL ) 
       AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT lastname 
                         FROM   tcpd_personel 
                         WHERE  gal.NAME = tcpd_personel.lastname) 
             AND gal.NAME IS NOT NULL ) 
       AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT firstname 
                         FROM   tcpd_personel 
                         WHERE  gal.given_name = tcpd_personel.firstname) 
             AND gal.NAME IS NOT NULL ) 
       AND gal.country = 'Germany' 
GROUP  BY NAME, 
          given_name, 
          mail 
HAVING ( Count(*) > 1 ))
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte_mycount
```